# HtmlAgilityPack how to get div that gets added by js?

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping, .net-core, html-agility-pack

Today I've wanted to write a webscraper that searches through a calendar website and finds the tags of events, so I can search through them and get info about who worked for the event.

The Problem is: The div I want to search for gets added by js, so how do I get it with htmlagilitypack?

The Calendar Website: https://esel.at/termine

My Code:

```cs
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace ESEL_Scraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                string Url = $"https://esel.at/termine";
                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
                HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content']").ToArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++) {
                          Console.WriteLine(nodes[i].InnerText);    
                }
            
        }
       
    }
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectNodes returns null when it doesn't find what you're looking for.  So that's why you get the null exception.  There are no "div" elements with class = "content".  If you change to a class that is used by a div element on that page you'll get results.

With HtmlAgility pack "SelectNodes" you need to do a null check in some way before using the result.

Comment: But I checked in the HTML of the Website, there is a class "content".

Comment: Okay, I think I know why it doesn't work. The div with the class "content" gets added by js. Does anyone know how to get the div yet?

Answer (score 0):

Short anwser: You can't. Parsing the web page for data, that gets added when the page loads is not possible by using HtmlAgilityPack - the initial source code of the page doesn't have the data.
Long anwser: There is probably some API call that gets the data for the events, and is then pushed via javascript to the page. Try to figure out what URL is used, and try to parse that. That would be this one: https://esel.at/api/termine/data?date=05.09.2020&selection=false

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated Javascript append the content. Using basic network inspecting you will see that there is another network request.
[image]

What you get here is data in JSON format which gets appended in HTML using Javascript.
Instead of using HtmlAgility pack you will need to parse JSON. In the example below I have used Newtonsoft.Json package to do that.

Here is the code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ESEL_Scraper
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Simply create request to the API and deserialize JSON using the Root class

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

            // Set the date you want in the link, in this example it's 06.09.2020
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://esel.at/api/termine/data?date=06.09.2020&selection=false");
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en,hr;q=0.9");
            request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "");
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            //Deserialize Json
            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseFromServer);
            foreach (var el in myDeserializedClass.termine)
            {
                //Get any field you need
                Console.WriteLine(el.title);
                Console.WriteLine(el.location);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    // Based on the JSON response https://pastebin.com/Xa5gSp50  I have generated classes using this website: https://json2csharp.com/
    public class Termine
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string startdate { get; set; }
        public string startdatetime { get; set; }
        public string starttime { get; set; }
        public string enddate { get; set; }
        public List<object> runtime { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_credits { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string recommended { get; set; }
        public bool online_event { get; set; }
        public object feed_urls { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string sort_date { get; set; }
        public string sort_category { get; set; }
        public string location_url { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public List<string> next { get; set; }
        public DateTime now { get; set; }
        public List<string> date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public DateTime runtime { get; set; }
        public int upcoming { get; set; }
        public int running { get; set; }
        public int termine { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Termine> termine { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }
}
```